# Can I use an electric smoker without wood chips as an oven to cook a ham?

Tags: equipment, ham

I'm cooking a big dinner. I am wondering if I can use my electric smoker without woods chips like a second oven so I can free up space in oven inside. Will it cook my ham well? I don't want to smoke my ham.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't recommend it, but that said your ham by definition has already been cured and all you are really doing is heating it.

Smokers are optimized for smoking meats at a lower temperature than a traditional oven or fire. They use a combination of smoke and water moisture to make great moist smoked meat. You could easily make your own ham by taking a pig's leg bone and "smoking" it with or without wood chips.

You should always use a smoker outside, and not indoors. [Why can I have an indoor pizza/wood oven, but not a BBQ or smoker? (or can I...?)](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/85244/why-can-i-have-an-indoor-pizza-wood-oven-but-not-a-bbq-or-smoker-or-can-i)

Happy Easter!

Comment: This uses a rather specific defintion of *ham*; many meats sold as ham joints in many countries do need cooking.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are often marketed specifically for the purpose of being portable outdoor ovens.

They are usually not well insulated and are aimed at lower temperatures. It would be tricky to bake a cake in one. But meat is less fussy and it should work fine. Just keep an eye on the internal temperature (ideally, with a probe thermometer) so that you can adjust it before it overcooks.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the electric smoker as an oven for things like your side dishes..ones that wouldn't need high searing heat. For example.. roasting baked potatoes, or sweet potatoes, carrots and parsnips anything that can be done at a lower temperature like 250? You can also start like a pot roast or pulled pork roast ( if you aren't smoking it) in your regular oven and then move the meat to the electric smoker and use it as a "low and slow" oven... braising is usually done lower temps. You could also use the electric smoker as a hot box to keep food warm as well. I actually got a free electric smoker when buying furniture and plan on using it this Thanksgiving to free up oven space.